# How can I render strings with certain characters as value of input tag?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am passing an array of category names to my template and iterating through this to populate the value of checkbox elements.

`<input id={{"category"|add:escaped_cat_name}} type="checkbox" name="category" value={{category_name}}>`

Some of my category names contain spaces and ampersands but Django ignores these so "Fun & Gaming" becomes "Fun":

```
category_name: Fun & Gaming
<input id="categoryFun" type="checkbox name="category" value="Fun">

category_name: Business Expenses
<input id="categoryBusiness" type="checkbox name="category" value="Business">
```

In these examples, I would like the interpreted `value` to read the 'Fun & Gaming`and 'Business Expenses`

If I add a `safe` tag to the value it renders the value name as "Fun" & gaming, with the second part of the string still outside the value name.

I have tried writing a custom tag to deal with this behaviour but it seems as though this is Django's default and I can't figure out how to disable it.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're doing this wrong, the `value` attribute needs to be a value that can be submitted via the form, so it has to be form encoded. Wrap your input in a `<label>` or add a `<label for=...>` to have a label formatted for the users.

Comment: @dirkgroten is right, take a look to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer, and I know this answer will not be nice for you: *you should to learn a bit more about django, and about django forms*:

Handling and processing inputs by hand is an anti-pattern. The right way is to create a [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/) object and render the form in template.

You can learn about forms at [Working with forms djag's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/).

Let me copy here a [sample for checkboxe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets)s:

```
from django import forms

BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES = ('1980', '1981', '1982')
FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
    ('green', 'Green'),
    ('black', 'Black'),
)

class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    birth_year = forms.DateField(
           widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )
```

So then, we do not have to re-invent the wheel and just use Forms.

For your data:

```
>>> FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (
...     ('categoryFun', 'Fun & Gaming'),
...     ('categoryBusiness', 'Business Expenses'),
... )
>>> 
>>> class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
...     favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
...         required=False,
...         widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
...         choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
...     )
... 
>>> str( SimpleForm() )
'<tr><th><label>Favorite colors:</label></th>
<td>
  <ul id="id_favorite_colors">
  <li> 
    <label for="id_favorite_colors_0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_colors" 
             value="categoryFun" id="id_favorite_colors_0" />
        Fun &amp; Gaming
    </label>
  </li>...'
```